# Lot spam from unknown source

Tags: linux, postfix, spam, exim

Here is the email header and info that I got from aol abuse. This type of emails are being generated from my server randomly at a very low rate and IP is blacklisted very freuqently. After 2 weeks of effort, I am still not able to find the spammer:

---

```
Return-Path: <rosemaryzipn@gocaltech.com>
Received: from zircon.freezone.co.uk (zircon.freezone.co.uk [91.222.8.110])
    by mtaig-mcb01.mx.aol.com (Internet Inbound) with SMTP id 09111700012D7
    for <redacted@aol.com>; Sun,  9 Nov 2014 10:13:08 -0500 (EST)
Received: from rosemaryzipn by mailtn.zircon.freezone.co.uk with local (Exim 4.40)
    id YAkDpP-GlgNmv-5p
    for redacted@aol.com; Sun, 09 Nov 2014 23:57:32 +0000
To: redacted@aol.com
Subject: Photos from the most thrilling naked cocktail party in a bamboo cafe for your enjoyment!
Message-Id: <YAkDpP-GlgNmv-5p@mailtn.zircon.freezone.co.uk>
From: "Versie Donelly" <rosemaryzipn@gocaltech.com>
Date: Sun, 09 Nov 2014 23:57:32 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
x-aol-global-disposition: G
Authentication-Results: mx.aol.com;
    spf=neutral (aol.com: the domain gocaltech.com reports a neutral SPF policy.) smtp.mailfrom=gocaltech.com;
x-aol-sid: 3039ac1a32a1545f84843484
X-AOL-IP: 91.222.8.110
X-AOL-SPF: domain : gocaltech.com SPF : neutral

<html><body>Hello, love muscle!<br>When my naughty hottest friend and me went to the beach I was wondering<br>
if we could see a proper nook to spend some time and have a good cocktail.<br>
Luckily, we found a perfect place - a sweet bamboo cafe on the sea shore where we spent our nights.<br>
<a href="http://ridiqee.loveandpickup.net/">See new naked pics at my profile</a> to appreciate a breathtaking party that we had.<br>
Be ready to see <a href="http://ridiqee.loveandpickup.net/">many perfect spots and <syn32> naked curves!</a></body></html>
```

---

Server is plesk 11 with CentOS 6. Is there any information present in this header, using which I can know origin of spammer.

Answer (score 3):

`Received: from rosemaryzipn by mailtn.zircon.freezone.co.uk with local (Exim 4.40)`

Looks like you have some spambot on your host. That bot submit messages locally, not over SMTP. That can be some vulnerable CMS like wordpress or even plesk itself.

Comment: any help to track it? lsof ?

Comment: You can't track this in fact. Message is submitted via unix socket by user www-data despite of real file name. The only way is to compare current sites with backup copies to detect differences.